# Stuck at splash screen

Tags: 14.04

How to fix Splash screen problem in ubuntu 14.04 after accidentally uninstalling python.
I tried recovery mode option but found it not of much use.
I am looking for step-by-step solution to fix it.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you managed to get to the recovery menu like [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qw3_vQFb7zo/UEyS2gfQoxI/AAAAAAAAGXI/dWc6iE79IVY/s1600/recovery-mode-ubuntu-1.png)?

Comment: Yes i managed to get there

Comment: Yes i managed to get there and as per the solution found on different sources, i ran the command "mount -o remount, rw" but it din't helped.

Comment: Then choose the option 'resume' and update what had happend - any error?

Comment: I chose the 'resume' option, it then again start loading ubuntu and get stuck again at splash screen(screen is somewhat different looking this time but result is same).

Comment: Is there anything written on the "splash screen" when using "resume" or as you said is just another look of a clear splash saying "loading ubuntu" or picture or whatever... Probably you have problems with the X server and will need some more information about your hardware. So edit your original question and add: laptop model and video card model.

Comment: Also try to run in the  _recovery menu_ and choose this time _faisafeX_ .

Comment: Laptop Model---- Toshiba PA5024U-1BRS

Comment: Video card --- 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel 2nd gen core processor Family integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: And what happened with _faisafeX _ option?

Comment: I am not getting any 'failsafeX' option in recovery menu. My recovery menu option are :-  resume, clean, dpkg, fsck, grub, network, root & system-summary

Comment: Toshiba PA5024U-1BRS  seems to be the ID of your battery :)... please be more careful and give perhaps the serial ID and the model of the laptop following  the [demonstration on the website of Toshiba](https://www.toshiba.co.uk/registration/help?helpField=serial)

Comment: I got it using terminal. My laptop serial number is--- 4C021541Q

Comment: Boot in _recovery menu_ , then choose _network_ set up your network and then go to _root_ and when you have the console, run `mount -o remount, rw /`. Then `apt-get install curl`. Then `lshw | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us `. Then give us the link that the command will give you as result.

Comment: Sorry but it's unable to set up a network and i think i should reinstall my operating system.

Comment: And Thank you very much for your help and efforts.

Comment: Unfortunately your laptop seems not to be registered in Toshiba DB (unless they separate the DB by world zones), and I did not manage to find the desired information.  Most probably your problem is with the video driver / X configuration. You may try to install 16.04 instead as it is not using X and could be more "typical user friendly" than 14.04 for your machine.  Good luck!

Comment: I will definitely consider your advice. Thank you for your time.